# If $G$ contains subgroup $H$ with $|G : H| = p^n$ such that $H \cap H^x = 1$ for $x \notin H$, then $G$ has a unique Sylow $p$-subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H \le G$ be a subgroup of the finite group $G$ such that $|G : H| = p^n$ for some prime $p$. If 
$$
 H \cap H^x = 1
$$ 
for $x \in G \setminus H$, then $G$ has a unique (hence normal) Sylow $p$-subgroup (i.e. $G$ is $p$-closed).

Can you help me solving this?

I know that as $|G : H| = p^n$ we have $P \cap H \in \mbox{Syl}_p(G)$
for each $P \in \mbox{Syl}_p(G)$ and $O_p(H) \le O_p(G)$. As if $|H| = p^k\cdot m$ with $(p,m) = 1$ it is $|G| = p^{n+k}m$. If $P \in \mbox{Syl}_p(G)$, then as $|P : P \cap H| \le |G : H| = p^n$ and $|P| = p^{k+n}$ we must have $|P\cap H| \ge p^k$, and $|P \cap H| \le p^k$ as the intersection is a $p$-group in $H$.
So that $O_p(H) \le P \cap H$ for each Sylow $p$-subgroup, i.e. it lies in the intersection of all Sylow $p$-subgroups, hence $O_p(H) \le O_p(G)$.

That is all I got, the property for $H$ is similar to a t.i. subgroup which is self-normalizing (or malnormal subgroup), or that $G$ is a Frobenius group with complement $H$ of prime power index.

Comment: The condition is equivalent to $G$ being a Frobenius group, so you can just use the standard theory of Frobenius groups. Alternatively, you can prove it directly using an easy counting argument. Since $|\cup_{x \in G}(H \setminus \{1\})^x| = |G|-p^n$, the remaining elements must form the unique Sylow subgroup.

Comment: You mean $|G \setminus \bigcup_x (H \setminus\{1\})^x)| \le |G| -  p^n$? So we have at most $p^{n+k}m - p^n = (p^km - 1)p^n$ elements left, a Sylow subgroup must contain $p^{n+k}$ elements, but we do not know much for example about $m$ so I do not think that these conditions are restrictive enough to force that just one Sylow subgroup is possible. PS: I would avoid using theorems about Frobenius groups if possible, as this is not presented in the book from which this exercise comes from.

Comment: What I wrote was correct! Putting $|H|=m$, the union of the conjugates of $H \setminus \{1\}$ has size exactly $p^n(h-1) = |G|-p^n$, and a Sylow subgroup of $G$ has size exactly  $p^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will just explain the answer of @Derek.

First notice that $H$ must be $p'$ group. To see this,

Let $K$ be a sylow $p$ subgroup of $H$ and let it be contained $P$ where $P$ is a sylow $p$ subgroup of $G$.

Clearly we have $K=H\cap P$. Let $x\in N_P(K)-K$. ($x$ exists as normilizer grows in $p$ groups.). Then clearly $x\notin H$ but $H\cap H^x\geq K$ which shows $K=1$.

As $H$ is $p'$ group, $H^x\cap P=1$ for any $x$ and for any Sylow $p$ subgroup of $G$.

Hence, $T=(G-\cup H^x)\cup \{e\}$ contains all sylow $p$ subgroup of $G$. Notice that $N_G(H)=H$ which means $H$ has exacly $|G:H|$ conjugate.

Then $|\cup H^x|=|G:H|.(|H|-1)+1=|G|-|G:H|+1\implies |T|=|G:H|=p^n$.

Above counting argument shows that $|T|=|P|$. As $P\subseteq T$, $P=T$ and $P$ is the uniqe sylow $p$ subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Thank you, thinking about Derek's hint I found another way to show that $|H|$ is not divisible by $p$. Let $H$ act on its $p^n$ right cosets in $G$, then as $Hgx = Hg \Leftrightarrow x \in H^g$, which has trivial intersection with $H$ if $g \notin H$, we find that $H$ is the unique fixed point of this action. Hence by orbit-stabilizer $1 \equiv |G : H| \pmod{|H|}$. But now as $a \equiv b \pmod{m}$ implies $(a, m) = (b,m)$ we find that $(p^n, |H|) = (1,|H|) = 1$, i.e. $p$ is not a divisor of $|H|$. But your proof is more fundamental, so thanks for sharing!

Comment: you are welcome Stefan. I wonder that which book you are following.

Comment: Its Kurzweil, Stellmacher *Theory of Finite Groups*, and exercise 3.2.6. Later they also discuss Frobenius groups, but as this exercise appears before their discussion I suppose the reader is not assumed to know about them.

Comment: I did not read this book before. Is there any particulur reason for you to follow this book ?

Comment: Yes it does not assume. You are right.

Comment: This seems seems to cover a wide range of topics and was recommended by others, but it is quite terse and the arguments are short, and I find it sometimes a little bit difficult, but overall good. You can find this book, just google its name, if you want to take a look.