# If Sylow $p$-subgroup has index $p+1$ and $O_p(G) = 1$, then $|G| = pq^r$ and $G$ contains elementary abelian normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $S \in \mbox{Syl}_p(G)$ be nontrivial such that $|G : S| = p + 1$. Then either $O_p(G) \ne 1$ or $p + 1 = q^r$ with $q$ prime and there exists an elementary abelian normal subgroup of order $p + 1$ in $G$.

Can you help me solve this?

Some thoughts of mine: I see that if $O_p(G) = 1$, then as $O_p(G) = \bigcap_{g\in G} S^g = S_G$, which is the kernel of the action of $G$ on the cosets of $S$, we have an embedding of $G$ into $S_{p+1}$, hence $|G|$ divides $(p+1)!$ and with $|G| = p^k(p+1)$ we find that $p^k$ divides $p!$, so that $k = 1$ because $p!$ has $p$ just once as prime divisor. So we know $|G| = p(p+1)$ and the Sylow $p$-subgroups are isomorphic to $C_p$ and as $O_p(G) = 1$ we must have at least two distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups, which have has cyclic groups of $p$-order trivial intersection. Further by the Sylow Theorems we find that we must have exactly $p+1$ Sylow $p$-subgroups, and as two of them intersect trivial they contains $(p+1)(p-1) + 1$ elements. Hence we have $p(p+1) - ((p+1)(p-1) + 1) = (p+1) + 1$ elements left, which gives if we have just one subgroup remaining it must have order $p+1$. Also we have $N_G(S) = S$ as $|G : N_G(S)| = p + 1 = |G : S|$. This is all I got this far, do not know if I am on the right track...

Comment: I find it helpful to observe that the action of $G$ by conjugation on the Sylow $p$-subgroups is a $2$-transitive Frobenius group. There is no need to quote the theorem that a Frobenius group has a regular normal subgroup. The nontrivial elements not in a conjugate of $P$ (i.e. the fixed point free elements) are all conjugate under the action of $S$, so they must all have the same prime order $q$. Now everything follows easily.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but is this easy to see that i) the nontrivial elements not in $\bigcup_g P^g$ are conjugate by $S$, and ii) these elements form a normal subgroups? Point ii) is seen by recognizing that it acts as a Frobenius group, but if possible I would avoid the theory of Frobenius groups, as this is an exercise from a book which treats Frobenius groups in a later chapter.

Comment: They are all conjugate, because there are $p$ of them, $|S|=p$ and none of them are centralized by $S$. Since they all have order $q$, $p+1$ must be a power of $q$, so they must (together with the identity) form the unique Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G$.

Comment: But what makes you sure that they form a single subgroup? I mean, by noticing that $G$ is a Frobenius group it is implied by the well-known, but highly nontrivial, structure theorem about such groups; do you have that in mind or is there another simple fact implying that? As said I would avoid citing facts about Frobenius groups if possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found that $|G|=p(p+1)$ . Let $q$ be a prime divisior of $p+1$ and $x$ be an order of $q$.

Note that $x^S$ has $p$ elements as $x$ does not commute any elemets of $S$. (otherwise $S\cap S^x\neq 1$). We see that the set $G-\cup S^x$ has $p$ elemets of order $q$. This argument shows that $p+1$ has a uniqe prime divisior.

Thus, $|G:S|=q^r$ and $S\cap S^x =1$. By previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522310/if-g-contains-subgroup-h-with-g-h-pn-such-that-h-cap-hx-1-for/1522366#1522366), $G$ is $q$ closed. Hence, $G=QS$ and $Q$ is normal in $G$. To see that $Q$ is abelian, notice that $S$ acts on $Q$ with exactly two orbits. $Q'$ must be $S$ invariant. Then we have $Q'=Q$ or $Q'=1$. The first one is imposible as $Q$ is an $q$ group.

Comment: Oh yes, somehow I did not saw its relation to the previous exercise O_o